# multithread rendering performance

Tags: vulkan

I am simulating multiple users rendering with my program on my computer with multiple threads. I wonder why my fps counter tells me that the performance on all threads is the same, regardless of the different data I am using on those threads. I mean, for some data, the rendering is slower, due to the complexity of the scene. However, when I mix a larger and more difficult-to-render dataset with a faster-to-render one, each scene is rendered with the same fps on different threads. That does not seem intuitive for me.

Best,
Lily

Comment: That depends on the structure of the threads, command buffers, queues, and the relationships between. As well as how your "fps counter" works.

Comment: my vulkan program is wrapped in a class. each thread is an instance of the class. as for fps counter, I used the code by sascha willems,

Comment: GPU drivers will throttle applications so that can't easily take over a system, look for a setting that will allow your app use more GPU cycles. (and look into applying those settings programmatically)

Comment: @pmw1234 I don't understand what you mean. will using more GPU cycles make the program faster?

Comment: GPU drivers control app performance in a way similar to CPU operating systems limiting graphics apps to about 60fps. This can be disabled in the GPU settings usually.

Comment: @pmw1234 Ah, I know about this. I don't think this is the issue though, because the fps can vary from 100fps to 30fps for three threads, depending on the data.

Comment: The best way to determine this is to measure the frame time in the code which is GPU time + CPU time and compute an expected frame rate. That takes the guess work out of the equation.